# Ratio of Poisson Distributions (Possible mistake on exams by instructor)

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I found the following on a practice final of one of my students and it does not seem to add up.

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from a Poisson distribution $f(k\vert \theta) = \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^k}{k!}$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $S(X)= \frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$ is an ancillary statistic (i.e. its distribution does not depend on $\theta$).

I think what they have in mind is that the above expression is scale invariant which it is. The issue is however twofold:

1. $S$ is not well defined when $X_1 = X_2 = \dots = X_n = 0$ which happens with non-zero probability.
2. The scale invariant property of the expression is not sufficient. One also needs to show that the $X_i$'s follow what is known as the scale model, namely there are Random Variables $W_i$ which **do NOT depend on $\theta$** and a constant $c$ such that: $X_i = cW_i$. To my knowledge this is not the case for Poisson.

Is this a case of a simple oversight or am I missing something obvious?

(Note: This is a standard graduate course in statistics where students are expected to identify various kinds of statistics (sufficient, complete, ancillary etc) and apply these ideas to relevant theorems such as Basu's theorem.)

Comment: Maybe it is a typo and the instructor really meant to define $S(X)$ as $\frac{X_1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate that would have a distribution which depended on $\theta$: for example you would have $P(S=0)=e^{-\theta}$ in your suggestion, while originally you had $P(S=0)=e^{-\theta}-e^{-n\theta}$ and $P(S=\frac00)=e^{-n\theta}$

Comment: The statement is true when the family of distributions being considered has a parameter $\theta$ which is a scale parameter (or a function of scale, such as a rate parameter) and the probability of the sum being $0$ is $0$.  An example might be an exponential distribution (e.g. from a Poisson process); but a Poisson distribution fails on both counts

Comment: @Henry. That is correct. I believe Exp($\theta$) is the classic example, which I think is what they were inspired by. This shows however, that one needs to be very careful when working with heuristics (in this case scale invariance) as they are not always sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right; this is wrong. The problem of well-definedness could perhaps be solved by treating “undefined” as a special value of the statistic or defining it in some way, but the distribution for the defined values depends on $\theta$ anyway. For instance, $S(X)=1$ iff all $X_i$ except $X_1$ are $0$, and the probability for this clearly depends on $\theta$.

What they might have meant:

- The same statement for the normal distribution  (where the undefined case has probability $0$)
- The conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $\sum_iX_i$ doesn’t depend on $\theta$.

Comment: It is true for a normal distribution with mean $0$ where $\theta$ is the variance or standard deviation, but not for a normal distribution where $\theta$ is the mean while the variance is a positive constant or does not depend on $\theta$

Comment: @Henry: Thanks, yes, I guess I meant the standard normal distribution.